# IE9: Validation message not getting cleared

Tags: asp.net, validation, internet-explorer-9

I am using an upload control which accepts only image files.If I select any non-image files I will be showing a validation error message "File type is invalid". The upload control i use is as follows

```
<UC:UploadControl runat="server" ID="file_logo" IsRequired="false" ReqValidationGroup="jpg" onkeypress="Javascript:CheckNumeric(event);"   RequiredFieldMessage="Please upload Image file" CheckFileType="true" Width="870" Height="100" CheckDimension="false" RegexpFieldMessage="File type is invalid." FileFormats="gif,GIF,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG" RegDisplay="true"  />
```

I use another link to clear the error validation message. The code is

```
<a href='javascript:chkFileTypes("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_file_logo_uploadfiles");clearInvalidLabel("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_file_logo_uploadfiles")' >Clear File</a><br />
```

My Javascript function used to clear validation message is

```
function clearInvalidLabel(control) {
if (control == "ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_file_logo_uploadfiles") $("span[id$='file_logo_regexpType']").hide();
if (control == "ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_PopUp_logo_uploadfiles") $("span[id$='PopUp_logo_regexpType']").hide();}
```

Now if I again select an improper file using UploadControl, the error validation message is not getting displayed(Only in IE9). It works perfectly in other browsers. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hard-coding IDs is easy to break. Try using the `ClientID` to access the control in JavaScript.

```
<a href='javascript:chkFileTypes("<%=UploadFilesControl.ClientID%>");clearInvalidLabel("<%=UploadFilesControl.ClientID%>")'>Clear File</a>
```

I would use the ClientID to get the validation labels too:

```
$("#<%=regexpType.ClientID%>").hide();
```